# Cancel return result from gui popup

Tags: powershell

I am using this function to invoke Popup to insert information:

```
function Set-Popup ([String]$Title, [String]$Label) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 150;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

##############Define text label1
$TextLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$TextLabel1.Left = 25;
$TextLabel1.Top = 15;
$TextLabel1.Width = 200;

$TextLabel1.Text = "$Label";

##############Define error label

$ErrorLabel = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$ErrorLabel.Left = 25;
$ErrorLabel.Top = 65;
$ErrorLabel.Width = 450;

############Define text box1 for input
$TextBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$TextBox1.Left = 250;
$TextBox1.Top = 10;
$TextBox1.width = 200;

#############define Confirm button
$ConfirmButton = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$ConfirmButton.Left = 360;
$ConfirmButton.Top = 85;
$ConfirmButton.Width = 100;
$ConfirmButton.Text = “Confirm”;

#############define Cancel button
$CancelButton = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$CancelButton.Left = 250;
$CancelButton.Top = 85;
$CancelButton.Width = 100;
$CancelButton.Text = “Cancel”;

############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$ConfirmBFunc = [System.EventHandler]{
$TextBox1.Text;
$form.Close();
};

$ConfirmButton.Add_Click($ConfirmBFunc);

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($ConfirmButton);
$form.Controls.Add($TextLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($ErrorLabel);
$form.Controls.Add($TextBox1);
$form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

return $TextBox1.Text
}
```

This works great as I was expecting but when it finishes and using the "return" cmdlet, it returns "Cancel" and after that the info I inserted in the text box.
Kill me but i really don't understand what returns the "cancel" string.

[image: Here I inserted CompTest in the Text Box]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cancel` is coming from the [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog) method, which automatically returns the result to the caller.  In the case of PowerShell, that means it will automatically be displayed in the console.

To suppress it, do this:

`$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null`

If you actually want the result, but want to set it to something else, you can do it in your event handler before closing (and omit the `Out-Null` from above):

```
$ConfirmBFunc = [System.EventHandler]{
        $TextBox1.Text
        $form.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
        $form.Close()
    }
```

Comment: It still throws me a Cancel result even after writing Out-Null :(

Comment: Check my example again - I had a typo.  Be sure you're putting the `Out-Null` in the correct place (after `ShowDialog`)